# Change ListView CellTemplate based on state of item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, refactoring, celltemplate

I have a ListView that is has an ObservableCollection as its ItemsSource, and it has several columns. One of these is a State column which, depending on the current state of the item, shows a different message. Currently this is implemented as a basic string, and while it works it is far from pretty or userfriendly. I want to be able to vary the sort of output to more properly suit the state of the item.

I did do some research and know that I need to use a CellTemplate to affect the display, but all the different sorts of templates simply overwhelm me to the point where I can't figure out where to go next.

My code (excluding lots of other listview fluff) is as follows:

```
<ListView Name="itemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource listingDataView}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    ...
    <ListView.View>
         <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Item Information">
             ...
             <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=StatusMessage}" Width="283" Header="Status" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GVHeaderLeftAlignedStyle}" />
         </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Yes, the items have hardcoded 'Status Message' that get updated alongside other properties that are actually relevant for the code, causing ugly duplication elsewhere in my code. (And yes, I know this is far from pretty, but I want to improve this too.) That property would be called `ItemState` as I am not all that creative.

So, my question is: how can I vary this column to have the most suitable display for the given state? Textual descriptions will do for many states, but some are rather lengthy and might profit from a text with a progress bar besides it, and maybe some sort of time remaining. Another state would profit from having a clickable hyperlink. In other words, I think I need at least 3 different CellTemplates.

I realize it is a rather open-ended question that largely suffers from the design mistakes of someone (=me) who has rather little experience with WPF, but that is exactly why I'm hoping someone experienced can set me straight with some basic code before I make an even worse mess of things than I have already. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use triggers to change the content of the cell, e.g.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Status">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StateItem.HasError}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <!-- Possibly create another contentcontrol which differentiates between errors -->
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding StateItem.Error}"
                                                        Foreground="Red"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>

                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StateItem.HasError}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Image Source="Images/Default.ico"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Code gets a bit crazy that way though if you branch it further but it's a way to do it.

**Edit:** The setters should set the `ContentTemplate` instead of the `Content`, apparently otherwise no new controls may be created and only one row shows the proper content since the content can only have one parent.

Comment: Awesome. It took me some time to get everything working the way I wanted it to (although I may yet have to figure out how to stuff in multiple controls), but for now I am totally extatic having a progressbar in there. Thanks for your help. :)