# Make ProgressBar take available space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, binding

This question directly relates to (the accepted answer of) this question: [Change ListView CellTemplate based on state of item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907528/change-listview-celltemplate-based-on-state-of-item), which holds all the relevant XAML in the accepted answer.

One of these states requires a ProgressBar. Which works, except for the fact I can't get it to look and act the way I want it to, which is to take all available horizon and vertical space without taking more space than required.

In an attempt to solve this, I have tried to follow the suggestions given [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/30e95a03-1506-4797-a09c-1fe07ca934c9/), but nothing I do seems to have a single effect. The XxxContentAlignment options go ignored, no matter whether I apply them to `ContentControl`s, `ListViewItem`s or whatever else I came up with along the way. The Binding to the named element also fails, giving me a

```
Cannot find source for binding with reference
```

error which refers to its inability to find what the other answer calls `col1`. All other suggestions I have found are variations of these, either involving `ActualWidth` or its `ActualHeight` cousin, or stuff involving `RelativeSource` and `FindAncestor`.

At this point of trying to fix this rather trivial thing for the last 2 hours, I think I can really use the final nudge to show me in the right direction. (And probably point out the obvious mistakes I've been making...)

Comment: Where's your code?  How are we to know if you are doing it right or wrong?

Comment: See the first paragraph. As for doing it right/doing it wrong: the suggestions given there I implemented nearly to the letter, and I dare say they aren't quite rocket-science. I tried a lot of variations, the essential pieces of which I mentioned in the question as well, but what would you have me do beyond that? Recreate every single variety I remember trying? :)

Comment: Ah sorry about that.  When I see "I tried to do this but it doesn't work," I would expect to see code to go along with it.  Unfortunately that happens way too often here and is difficult to offer any good advice.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: Not a problem. I run into the issue of inexperienced programmers asking questions without doing any investigation or debugging themselves far too often. They cause people to think summarized problems or a lack of code constitutes a lack of effort and/or intelligence - while in reality, it is just someone cutting to the chase to save everyone a bit of time. By now, the question is already answered, but thank you for commenting anyway, Jeff. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is at a high level, i for one got it to stretch via changing the ItemStyle:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Some code i tested it on, just so you see that no `HorizontalAlignment` or `HorizontalContentAlignment` was set:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Status">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <ProgressBar Height="20"
                                                             Value="{Binding Id}" Minimum="0" Maximum="10"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>

                            <!-- ... -->
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Ah, so ItemContainerStyle is the piece of the puzzle that I was missing! I'll try it out after I am done watching my movies. :) However, I want to ask - would this not apply to _all_ elements I might put into that column, not just the ProgressBar? I take it I would need a seperate bunch of DataTriggers for the ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: It does not affect the other columns from what i've seen. At least text is still left aligned (possibly even if the TextBlock now stretches the whole width)

Comment: Consider it pre-emptive worrying on my part. :) I'll consider it answered as it does exactly what I'm asking for, thank you! (Off to the next weird problem that I might be able to ignore.)